# ZipForge not working

Tags: vb.net, zip, extract

I'm using the [ZipForge](http://www.componentace.com/.NET_zip_component_zipforge.htm) to extract an archive in VB.NET.
When I run the code I get no errors, but it doesn't extract any of the files. This is the code I'm using:

```
ZipForge1.FileName = "Archive.zip"
ZipForge1.OpenArchive(FileMode.Open)
ZipForge1.BaseDir = "C:\Extract"
ZipForge1.ExtractFiles()
```

Any help as to why this is not working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [CloseArchive](http://www.componentace.com/help/zf.net_guide/closearchive.htm) after you extract:

```
ZipForge1.CloseArchive()
```